# Detect that SKShapedNode is closed

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, 2d-games

In my future game(in SpriteKit), I need to draw circle-like shapes. I use `CGMutablePathRef` and `SKShapeNode` for drawing itself.

On `touchesEnded` I need to check if the user did close the circle or if there is a gap between start and end touches. 
(Strictly saying, it can be not only the right circle, I need to detect any closed shape, e.g. loop...)

How can I do this checking?

Comment: CGPath does not have an "intersect" function so there is no easy built in way to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Store the touches locations (points) in an array: `[yourArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:yourPoint]];`
2. Make a rect (size? your choice! the smaller it is, the more precise) around the first point in the array (first touch location).
3. Control if the rect also contains the last point in the array (last touch location).
4. If so, then close your path.

Comment: Storing the touch points is not an accurate method. Moving touch locations jump from point to point with gaps in between. This means you could cross a line and not have the same stored point in your array.

Comment: I agree, that this method loses some instances when the loop is made, not a circle. But for now, this is the best I have, and it pretty much allows me to do what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Why is stroring the touch points in an array not accurate methode? http://www.raywenderlich.com/61289/how-to-make-a-line-drawing-game-with-sprite-kit Apart from this, the answer is, to control, if the rect around the first point also contains the last touch point. If so, then the path can be closed.

Comment: This is what I actually did after you gave me a hint about that precision rectangle around the first touch.